# How to prevent first line from becoming a header when import multiple files txt files in Python and assigning each to a separate data frames?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, glob

I have 4 txt files that I have been able to import, make into data frame, and store in a list.  The files do not have headings in them which I cannot add in the files themselves.  When I run the code, it turns the first line into headings.  How do I modify this code so the first line does not become headings?  all_dfs is a list containing file names.

```
filenames = glob.glob("U32_*.txt")
all_dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames]
for dataframe, filename in zip(all_dfs, filenames):
    dataframe['filename'] = filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the pandas.read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> header : int, list of int, default ‘infer’
>
> Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is to infer the column names: if no names are
> passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are
> inferred from the first line of the file, if column names are passed
> explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None. Explicitly
> pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names. The header can be
> a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the
> columns e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be
> skipped (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter
> ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so
> header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of
> the file.
>
> names : array-like, optional
>
> List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None. Duplicates in this list are not allowed.

Since your files have no headers, the default behavior of inferring the column names won't work for you, and you'll need to specify `header=None` in your call to read_csv to override that default behavior. You'll likely also want to supply an array of `names` to provide the column names.

So it would look something like:

```
pd.read_csv(filename, names=['firstColName', 'secondColName'], header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, adding `header = None` without including names is exactly what I need since my files have different number of columns.